# Primefaces Ajax ItemSelect Event Not Supported

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have a pieChart in a dialog.When I click a pie on pieChart , I should be able to get index of the pie just like [the example.](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/interactiveCharts.jsf) . However, I get this error :

> ```
> <p:ajax> Event:itemSelect is not supported.
> ```

Here is the code I use :

```
 <p:dialog widgetVar="pieCharts" dynamic="true" id="pieCharts" closable="true" draggable="true" minimizable="true">
           <p:outputPanel autoUpdate="true" >
                  <h:form prependId="false">  
                                <p:pieChart id="typePie" value="#{browse.typePie}" legendPosition="e" fill="false" showDataLabels="true" sliceMargin="2"
                                            title="Type" style="width:400px;height:300px"/>   

                                <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{browse.createPieForFamily}" />
                  </h:form>
           </p:outputPanel>
 </p:dialog>
```

How can I solve this not supported error?

Note : I use primefaces 3.5RC1 version.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your p:ajax inside p:pieChart

```
<p:dialog widgetVar="pieCharts" dynamic="true" id="pieCharts" closable="true" draggable="true" minimizable="true">
   <p:outputPanel autoUpdate="true" >
       <h:form prependId="false">  
           <p:pieChart id="typePie" value="#{browse.typePie}" legendPosition="e" fill="false" showDataLabels="true" sliceMargin="2" title="Type" style="width:400px;height:300px">
                <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{browse.createPieForFamily}" />
            </p:pieChart>
        </h:form>
    </p:outputPanel>
</p:dialog>
```